# How to migrate kubernetes PVs and PVCs from one cluster to another?

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I have a Kubernetes cluster (v1.16) set up on my servers. Also, I have a Ceph cluster running on a different set of servers and is used in my Kubernetes cluster as a storage class. In order to upgrade my Kubernetes cluster to version 1.26 I decided to run another cluster on a different set of servers and then move my applications there. In addition, my newly created cluster will use the same Ceph cluster as the old one. However, I don't know how to backup my data (i.e. my PV data). I found a couple of tools. `pv-migrate` is not applicable to my use case, since it needs a `LoadBalancer` service with a valid IP which I don't have. `velero` also backs up data in cloud environments. What is the best way to backup my data and restore it in  the new cluster? Is there any way to reference old volumes in the new cluster and use them in my pods?

Comment: What sizes we talking about?

Comment: @Kyslik about 60Gb in total

Comment: Hi, maintainer of `pv-migrate` here. You can give it a shot to the `local` strategy. It is an experimental migration strategy which is not as reliable as the others, but might worth a shot: https://github.com/utkuozdemir/pv-migrate/blob/master/USAGE.md#strategies